# When using .searchable modifier with ScrollView, occasionally the view bounces

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using a ScrollView combined with a .searchable modifier within a NavigationStack, there is an inconsistent bounce behavior that occurs. I am currently using iOS 17.2 as the target. I've tried many workarounds to create a more consistent experience but I can't seem to eliminate the occasional bounce. This almost always happens when the search bar is first selected as well.

Example of the problem:

[image: Example of the problem.]

I've created a very simple test view with only a ScrollView with a VStack containing Text:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var query: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Hey")
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $query)
            .navigationTitle("Test View")
        }
    }
}
```

Even with this simple view, the bounce still happens. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

I've tried using a geometry reader and other methods to see if it was a framing issue, but even breaking the view down to a simple scenario still produces the issue. I expect it to smoothly animate upwards but it does not.